# Integral Notation , integrating over integers.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

What would it mean to integrate over a set of numbers like the integers? For example
if given an integral whose bounds are negative to positive infinity, one can express this as:

What I was thinking is that this would not come to much use since this would be like integrating a point. Which would yield zero for every integer over which you integrate. I suppose if you were integrating a delta function this would be the only exception.

\begin{equation}\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)dx \ \text{vs.} \int_\mathbb{Z} f(x)dx  \end{equation}

Comment: If you are talking about Riemann integration or Lebesgue integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure then the result will be zero. If you use the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}$ then you have $\int_\mathbb{Z} f(n) d |\cdot|(n) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f(k)$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Are you familiar with the notion of a Lebesgue integral, that would give you the right definition. Also try to use MathJaxx instead of a picture if you can. Greetings,

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference I recommend you look here for posting posts its very helpful.\

Comment: Great Question. +1

Comment: Not of much use. With a function, yields zero, and with delta distributions yields a discrete summation.

Comment: What does the FTC say about an integral on an interval whose starting and ending endpoints are the same? What if I have several of them?

Answer (score 4):

In Lebesgue's theory of integration, one can integrate over any "measurable" set of real numbers, and non-measurable sets are exotic things not encountered in practice. (In the context of probability theory, however, sets failing to be measurable with respect to certain sigma-algebras that must be considered. But you should consider this parenthetical comment optional until you learn some of the relevant things in probability theory.)

- By the usual way of assigning a measure to a set of real numbers, the measure of the set of all integers is $0,$ and consequently if one integrates any function over that set one gets $0.$
- But one can assign other measures to the set of all integers, in which a positive number is assigned to some or all sets containing just one integer. The most usual way to do this is that the measure of each set $\{n\}$ is $1.$ In that case, the integral over the set of all integers is just the sum of an infinite series.